# Spring boot: configure hsqldb datasource to persist data

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, hsqldb

I am trying to create a spring boot app. I want to persist data using hsql database.

first I did include hsqldb maven dependency and springboot auto-configure is working fine, but after app restart data is lost.

Then I did include following configuration in application.peoprties file

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:hsqldb:file:testdb.script
spring.datasource.username = SA
spring.datasource.password = 

#JPA properties
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
```

But data is still not persisted.
What should be configuration for persisting data?
Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default for `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` is create-drop if you use an embedded database. Update this in your properties to `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate` or `none`

Comment: thanks for quick response. `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate` did solve the problem.  what is difference between  `spring.jpa.generate-ddl` and `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto`

Comment: `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` - support hibernate feature, which is not in jpa

Comment: I did updated `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update' in order to create table corresponding to Entity automatically